# Flutter App crashes when taking pictures erratically

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on an app that includes taking pictures and sending them to the backend. Nothing crazy, and everything seems to be good. Since we need to send information back to the server, I need implemented something such that the app verifies the connection token's validity every time the App's state goes from Paused or Exited to Resumed.

That being said, a friend of mine was testing the app and apparently taking pictures from his Samsung S20 FE (android 12) can crash the app. It happens at seemingly random times, so I've plugged his phone into Android Studio and go this error message:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Error During Communication: Error occured while Communication with Server with StatusCode: 404
```

That's really weird because we don't try to send the pictures until a button is pressed and this happens right as the picture is taken. So I thought it might be my code that checks for lifecycle changes, since it does call the backend to check on the auth token, but it's surrounded with a `.then` and `.onError` which should catch the network error before it's propagated to the app.

It also bugs me that I've never been able to reproduce it with my OnePlus 6 (Android 11) or using a simulator. I'll be joining some code below to illustrate my functionalities. Any idea why I'm having this problem and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance !

*App lifecycle function*

```
  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print("State changed to: $state");
    switch(state){
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        final LoginManager loginManager = locator<LoginManager>();
        final userToken = await loginManager.getUserTokenFromStorage();
        if (userToken != null) {
          final Future<LoginResponse?> loginResponse = locator<LoginManager>().verifyToken(refreshToken);
          loginResponse.then((value) {
            if(value == null) {
              _showTimeoutDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
            }
          }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
            _showTimeoutDialog(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
          });
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        break;
    }
  }
```

Note that `showTimeoutDialog` shows a dialog and properly disconnects the user, no information is sent whatsoever.

*Taking a picture function*

```
  Future<File?> _getPhotoFromCamera(bool isSelfie) async {
    return ImagePicker()
        .pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      preferredCameraDevice:
      isSelfie ? CameraDevice.front : CameraDevice.rear,
    )
        .then((value) => value != null ? File(value.path) : null);
  }
```

Uses the flutter image_picker package

Comment: possibly, the app is being cleared from background due to low memory as mentioned here https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#handling-mainactivity-destruction-on-android